# Chrome executing code twice while IE is not

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've made a small image-modifier javascript function which gets executed twice in Chrome but once in IE. I can't seem to find the issue that causes this.

The script itself gets executed once. I've put a 'console.log' message at the top of the script to verify this. There's also a log message at the start of the function, this gets executed twice in chrome, but once (as it should) in IE.

This is the HTML code I use for the image:

```
<img src="/images/test.jpg" grayscale="/images/test.jpg?edit&grayscale" alt="" onload="grayscaleHover(this, .75);">
```

Comment: "Check the source of the code in the chrome inspector for 'modifiers.js'." what is this modifier.js? you have to post the source in tehe question

Comment: Don't post a link and ask us to View Source, as you're likely to change what's at the link after, and make this question less useful to people who later come across it.

Comment: remember the onload event is executet every time you change source

Comment: Removing the onload event and replacing it by a script tag which executes the function with a 'document.getElementById' argument didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The page is loaded by an AJAX call, which is loaded after an animation in jQuery, e.g.:

```
$("#loadbar").animate({...},500,function(){ $.ajax here... });
```

It seems that the $.ajax part got executed twice there for some reason. This looks like a jQuery bug.

Answer (score -2):

Hmm... when do want the function to be called? I think it is the fact that you call it at `onload` which is the problem. Maybe do it only on `onmouseover="your_function"`

Comment: The body of the onmouseover attribute is a statement which will be executed within the mouseover handler. Removing parenthesis will do nothing.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to say or what the parenthesis have to do with anything.

Comment: onmouseover is not an option. I need the code to be executed only ONCE because the script actually changes the code. - 

It replaces the IMG tag with several divs and some jquery code (see modifiers.js)